# how to fix jquery error TypeError: 'click' called

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm working on a project which is a control panel for minecraft servers, this is the configuration section in this and created a form that the user must complete to make the configuration and to send the values ​​eh used ajax but I get this error : TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement.
How can I solve that 
I speak Spanish so the document is in Spanish

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <?php 
  $file = "../home/server.properties";
  if (file_exists($file)) {
   $file = file("../home/server.properties");
   if (!str_replace("allow-flight=false", "allow-flight=false", $file)) {
    $fly = "true";
   } else {
    $fly = "false";
   }
   if (!str_replace("force-gamemode=false", "force-gamemode=false", $file)) {
    $forgm = "true";
   } else {
    $forgm = "false";
   }
   if (str_replace("spawn-npcs=false", "spawn-npcs=false", $file) == true) {
    $NPCS = "true";
   } else {
    $NPCS = "false";
   }
   if (str_replace("spawn-animals=false", "spawn-animals=false", $file) == true) {
    $animal = "true";
   } else {
    $animal = "false";
   }
   if (str_replace("online-mode=true", "online-mode=true", $file) == true) {
    $pirate = "false";
   } else {
    $pirate = "true";
   }
   $file2 =  implode('|',$file);
   if (strpos($file2, "pvp=true") == true) {
    $pvp = "true";
   } else {
    $pvp = "false";
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "difficulty=0") == true) {
    $diff = 0;
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "difficulty=1") == true) {
    $diff = 1;
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "difficulty=2") == true) {
    $diff = 2;
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "difficulty=3") == true) {
    $diff = 3;
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "enable-command-block=true") == true) {
    $command_block = "true";
   } else {
    $command_block = "false";
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "gamemode=0") == true) {
    $gm = 0;
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "gamemode=1") == true) {
    $gm = 1;
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "gamemode=2") == true) {
    $gm = 2;
   }
   if (strpos($file2, "spawn-monsters=true") == true) {
    $criaturas = "true";
   } else {
    $criaturas = "false";
   }
   if (file_exists("../motd12.save")) {
    $save1 = file("../motd12.save");
    $save1 = implode('|',$save1);
    $save1 = base64_decode($save1);   
    $motd = $save1;
    $not_exists = 0;
   } else {
    $not_exists = 1;
    $motd = "A Minecraft Server";
   }
   $svp = 1;
  } else {
   $svp = 0;
  }
   $js = 'var valuesL = ["'.$fly.'","'.$forgm.'","'.$NPCS.'","'.$animal.'","'.$pirate.'","'.$pvp .'","'.$diff.'","'.$command_block.'","'.$gm.'","'.$criaturas.'","'.$motd.'"];'; 
  ?>
  <?php 
   echo "<script>";
   echo $js;
   echo 'var svp = "'.$svp.'"';
   echo "</script>";
   ?>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Panel de Control ° Config</title>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Css/estilos.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../demo-files/demo.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../console/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="nav_bar">
    <div class="content">
     <a href="../index.php" class="btn-nav">General</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn-nav">Configuración</a>
     <a href="../PlugMods/" class="btn-nav">Plugins / Mods</a>
     <a href="../log/" class="btn-nav">Log</a>
    </div>
   </div>
 <div class="panel-control">
  <span class="titulo-text">Configuraciones </span>
  <div class="comp">
   <div class="save-config">
    Permitir volar: <select name="fly" id="fly">
     <option value="true">Si</option>
     <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Forzar modo de juego: <select name="forgm" id="forgm">
     <option value="true">Si</option>
     <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Spawnear NPCS: 
    <select name="npcs" id="npcs">
     <option value="true">Si</option>
     <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Spawnear animales: 
    <select name="animal" id="animal">
     <option value="true">Si</option>
     <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Permitir minecraft pirata:
    <select name="pirate" id="pirate">
     <option value="true">Si</option>
     <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Jugador contra jugador: 
    <select name="pvp" id="pvp">
     <option value="true">Si</option>
     <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Dificultad:
    <select name="dificulty" id="dificulty">
     <option value="pacifico">Pacifico</option>
     <option value="facil">Facil</option>
     <option value="normal">Normal</option>
     <option value="hard">Dificil</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Permitir bloque de commandos:
    <select name="command_block" id="command_block">
     <option value="true">Si</option>
     <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Modo de juego:
    <select name="npcs" id="npcs">
     <option value="survival">Survival</option>
     <option value="creativo">Creativo</option>
     <option value="aventura">Aventura</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    Generar Criaturas:
    <select name="criaturas" id="criaturas">
     <option value="true">Si</option>
     <option value="false">No</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    MOTD:
    <input type="text" id="motd" name="motd" placeholder="Motd del server">
    <br>
    <span class="respuesta"></span>
    <br>
    <button class="btn-submit" onclick="mifuncionchingona()" id="btn-submit">Save</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
<script>
 var dificultades = ["pacifico","facil","normal","hard"];
 var gamemodes = ["survival","creativo","aventura"];
 $(document).ready(function() {
  loadnames();
 });
 // funciones // 
 function loadnames() {
 $('#fly').val(valuesL[0]);
 $('#forgm').val(valuesL[1]); 
 $('#npcs').val(valuesL[2]);
 $('#animal').val(valuesL[3]);
 $('#pirate').val(valuesL[4]);
 $('#pvp').val(valuesL[5]);
 $('#dificulty').val(dificultades[valuesL[6]]);
 $('#command_block').val(valuesL[7]);
 $('#gm').val(gamemodes[valuesL[8]]);
 $('#criaturas').val(valuesL[9]);
 $('#motd').val(valuesL[10]);
 }
  $.get("stat.php", function(data,status) {
   $('#result').html(data);
   if (data == "Detenido") {
    var status = "detenido";
   } else {
    var status = "enlinea";
   }
  });
function mifuncionchingona() {
 var fly = $('#fly').val(),
   forgm = $('#forgm').val(),
   npcs = $('#npcs').val(),
   animal = $('#animal').val(),
   piratas = $('#pirate').val(),
   pvp = $('#pvp').val(),
   difficulty = $('#dificulty').val(),
   command_block = $('#command_block').val(),
   gm = $('#gm').val(),
   criaturas = $('#criaturas').val(),
   motd = $('#motd').val();
  var values = [fly,forgm,npcs,animal,piratas,pvp,dificulty,command_block,gm,criaturas,motd];
 if (status == "enlinea") {
  $.get('../stop.php', function(data) {
  
  });
  $.post('save.php', {
   "fly":values[0],
   "forgm":values[1],
   "npcs":values[2],
   "animal":values[3],
   "piratas":values[4],
   "pvp":values[5],
   "diff":values[6],
   "command_block":values[7],
   "gm":values[8],
   "criaturas":values[9],
   "motd":values[10]
  }, function(data, status) {
   console.log("Esperando "+data);
   $('.respuesta').html('Los cambios se an realizado con exito, el server se esta reiniciando!');
  });
 } else {
  $.post('save.php', {
   "fly":values[0],
   "forgm":values[1],
   "npcs":values[2],
   "animal":values[3],
   "piratas":values[4],
   "pvp":values[5],
   "diff":values[6],
   "command_block":values[7],
   "gm":values[8],
   "criaturas":values[9],
   "motd":values[10]
  }, function(data, status) {
   console.log("Esperando "+data); 
   $('.respuesta').html('Los cambios se an realizado con exito!');
   });
 }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

```
var values = [fly,forgm,npcs,animal,piratas,pvp,dificulty,command_block,gm,criaturas,motd];
```

the variable `dificulty` doesn't exist (is misspelled). This may be cascading and causing your error.